# If a plugin is initialized inside a try/catch, it doesn't keep the subscribers running

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Let me give first an introduction of my problem. I'm playing around with the "Creating your own plugin" tutorial. Until now I have 2 plugins, each of them has a subscriber callback to different topics. All the plugins are created correctly. The problem starts when I want to load them. The following is the code I'm using for that:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "polygon_loader_node");
  ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~/plugin_test");
  ros::NodeHandle g_nh;
  pluginlib::ClassLoader<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> poly_loader("plugin_test", "polygon_base::RegularPolygon");
  boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> polygon_plugins = poly_loader.createInstance("polygon_plugins::polygonPlugins");
  polygon_plugins->initialize();
  try
  {
    boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> plugin = poly_loader.createInstance(polygon_plugins::Triangle);
    plugin->initialize();
  }
  catch(pluginlib::PluginlibException& ex)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("The plugin failed to load for some reason. Error: %s", ex.what());
  }
 ros::spin();
 return 0;
}
```

In the code above, both plugins are initialized, however I can only go into the callback of the polygonPlugins one. However if I remove the try/catch, so both plugins are in the same level, then I can go into the Triangle plugin callback as well.
I suspect is something related with the location of the ros::spin(), however I don't know exactly the issue. I appreciate in advance your help.
Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314549/if-a-plugin-is-initialized-inside-a-try/catch,-it-doesn%27t-keep-the-subscribers-running/) by [Edu_](https://answers.ros.org/users/39805/edu_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is pretty typical C++ object lifetime: a C++ variable only lasts for the duration of block where it is created, and it is destroyed at the end of the block.

A block is the scope that starts at `{` and ends at the matching `}`

Therefore, since your `boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> plugin` variable is declared inside the `try {}`, it is also destructed at the end of that block.

You can fix this by moving the variable declaration outside of the `try {}` block, like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> plugin;
try {
    plugin = poly_loader.createInstance(polygon_plugins::Triangle);
    plugin->initialize();
} catch(pluginlib::PluginlibException& ex) {
    ROS_ERROR("The plugin failed to load for some reason. Error: %s", ex.what());
}
```

Now `boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> plugin` is declared within main's block (or scope), and lasts until the end of main.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edu_](https://answers.ros.org/users/39805/edu_/) on 2019-02-02**:
Cool, it worked! Thank you very much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-03**:
Please mark the question as answered by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, if you feel it has been answered.